# Vagrant not running Docker Image locally

Tags: docker, vagrant

I have the following Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/centos7"

  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
     d.run "jenkins/jenkins"
  end
end
```

**THE ERROR**

When I do a `vagrant provision`, it tries to reach out to the internet and does not find my local Docker image `jenkins/jenkins` that I know is working. I have also made sure to tag the docker image with `latest` This is the error message:

> Unable to find image 'jenkins/jenkins:latest' locally

**THE PROBLEM**

How can I tell Vagrant to look locally for this Docker image?

Comment: Is your `jenkins/jenkins` image on the host? I don’t think the Docker provisioner will use your host’s cache.

Comment: @Aankhen - it is on the host. Really? Is the Docker provisioner meant for inside the Vagrant?

Comment: [Yup:](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/docker.html) ‘As with all provisioners, the Docker provisioner can be used along with all the other provisioners Vagrant has in order to setup your working environment the best way possible. For example, perhaps you use Puppet to install services like databases or web servers but use Docker to house your application runtime. You can use the Puppet provisioner along with the Docker provisioner.’